# xml Child Elements

Tags: xml, crm

I'm trying to add and element before a child but not having much look. I think it's something obvious but i'm seeming nothing. What i'm trying to get and i have cut down to only the relevant information is

```
<lv_ordertype>Order</lv_ordertype>
<references>
<WebReference>
<reference_index>7</reference_index>
<reference_value>ST</reference_value>
<WebReference>
</references>
<customer />
<delivery>
```

but what i'm getting is

```
<lv_ordertype>Order</lv_ordertype>
<references>
<reference_index>7</reference_index>
<reference_value>ST</reference_value>
</references>
<customer />
<delivery>
```

My code looks like this for this section

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.81.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class WebSalesOrderreferences
 {
    private string reference_indexField;
    private string reference_valueField;
  //  [XmlArray("WebReferences")]
    private string reference_7Field;
    private string reference_8Field;
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string reference_index
    {
        get
        {
            return this.reference_indexField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.reference_indexField = value;
        }
    }
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string reference_value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.reference_valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.reference_valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it would be as simple as putting an xmlarray but that didn't work. Just for information this is pushing from Mircosoft CRM to our Accounts system

Kind Regards

Dan

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: How do i make it look like i need with the <WebReference> element. Sorry i didn't make it clear

Comment: Can anyone shed any light where i'm going wrong kind regards